# How to show multiple values from a single table using REGEXP_SUBSTR function and how to connect by on the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like this.

```
select  REGEXP_SUBSTR(tb.metadata_value,'[C]\s[a-z]',1,level),tb.*,level from tb
```

It has to return multiple values as separate rows for the same column. For instance, the row value would be like '[C 157+247   XXHD, C 157+1637 XXHD], It has to return two rows. I need to know how to use connect by itself.
Below is the sample data.

tb table:

```
  |Metadata_key|     |ReviewKey|  |Value                           
  |------------|     |---------|  |-----------------------------------------|    
  |123         |     |555      |  |[C 157+247   XXHD, C 157+1637 XXHD]      |
  |124         |     |555      |  |[C 157+247   XXHD, C 157+1637 XXHD]      |
  |125         |     |555      |  |[C 157+247   XXHD, C 157+1637 XXHD]      |
  |126         |     |666      |  |[C 157+7   XXHD,C 16+7 XXHD,C 14+5 XXHD] |
  |127         |     |666      |  |[C 157+7   XXHD,C 16+7 XXHD,C 14+5 XXHD] |
```

For every review key, values would repeat themselves. I want the output to be a series of values like the below:

Expected output:

```
 C 157+247 
 C 157+1637
 C 157+7
 C 16+7
 C 14+5
```

Comment: Do you need to do this for exactly one row (either because the table has only one row, or because you have a `where` clause that selects only one row), or do you need to do this for multiple input rows in a single query? If "many rows in a single query", is there a primary key in the table? If not, is the table really a table, or is it a view? Finally - are there always at most two comma-separated tokens, or is the number variable? If it is variable, do you need (at most) the first two tokens from each, or ALL tokens regardless of how many?

Comment: @mathguy, Hi Thank you for helping out. I have a where clause, where it could return multiple rows. I have the primary key in the table. I edited the question. I need all tokens. I edited the question to give sample values.

Answer (score 1):

You need the below CONNECT BY clause in your query -

```
WITH tb AS (SELECT '[C 157+247 XXHD, C 157+1637 XXHD]' metadata_value 
              FROM dual)
select  REGEXP_SUBSTR(tb.metadata_value,'[C]\s[^a-z,]+',1,level),tb.*,level
from tb 
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(metadata_value, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b8a41ff2c6e36e80e37cae31e8b92271)